# Are printer specs like 5760x1440 dpi real?

Tags: printing, printer, dpi

I understand that printer heads these days are made with semiconductor technology, microscopic piezo-actuated inkjets, etc..
But 5760dpi would mean a dot per every (25.4mm/5760 * 1000) ≈ 5 microns.
That is something you could only ever observe with a microscope at quite large magnification. For some sense of scale, a dot would have to be smaller than the diameter of a red blood cell.
Even the ~20 microns from the 1440dpi vertical resolution seems hard to believe. It's not a trivial task to position anything with that amount of accuracy, especially in a $50 plastic device.

So I'm a bit skeptical.

I got my Epson ET-2810 for regular printing and I'm very happy with it, but now I'm considering the idea of making my own printed circuit board stencils (which requires quite high resolutions, probably smaller than 0.1mm).

I am therefore wondering whether my printer is actually able physically to do it or if it's all just marketing nonsense.

Comment: As starting point size of particles of toner are around 5-10 μm so it is possible: https://www.nature.com/articles/pj201725

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, those numbers are not real.

Manufacturers use those high figures to give the user some indication of the kind of resolution a printer would need in order to produce its photo quality - **if** it were to use [conventional halftoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halftone) (with angled screens).

As modern lasers and inkjets use more advanced halftoning algorithms, they can produce crisper, clearer photos than a conventional halftone grid could produce. The "resolution" figures indicate that better photo quality.

And, of course, the higher numbers are also a marketing point.